# Meteor Account disable create-account function from website

Tags: javascript, meteor, authentication, meteor-accounts, user-accounts

[meteor login button ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Qz3.png)

I am using the meteor build-up package **meteor add accounts-ui** and **meteor add accounts-password** but I would like to disable the create-account function for other users except the administrator or just by using db like **db.insert.users().** 
 How could I make it and how could I set a administrator?

header.html

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          {{> loginButtons}}
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your shared code:

```
Accounts.config({
    forbidClientAccountCreation: true
});
```

Now no-one can create users directly. You'll have to add a method only accessible to the administrator which uses `Accounts.createUser`.